# Last Inserted Records According to Distinct Lookup Field

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to figure out a way to get last inserted records according to distinct lookup field. Let's say I have data like this;

---

*Field ----- Lookup ----- CreatedDate*

**Data1** ----- **User1** ----- **Inserted 5 min ago**

**Data2** ----- **User2** ----- **Inserted 6 min ago**

Data3 ----- User2 ----- Inserted 7 min ago

Data4 ----- User1 ----- Inserted 8 min ago

**Data5** ----- **User3** ----- **Inserted 10 min ago**

---

And I have distinct Lookup field Set like **`{User1,User2,User3}`**

I want to get data that highlighted with bold. Is it possible? Because getting data ordered by **`CreatedDate`** does not return what I need.

UPDATE: I know that I can grab records ordered by CreatedDate then inside a `for` I can get latest values for distinct fields. But I have a large data set. Because of this I need to avoid limits. But limiting to query, let's say 1000, might not always return record for every distinct lookup field. For User200 last inserted record might be 20 days ago. Then by limiting query to 1000 I might not get the record for User200.

Comment: Probably `Select FieldName from ObjectName where Lookup in: distinctUserList OrderBy Createddate desc`

Comment: @Mr.Frodo No. That would return my sample data list. I just want bold part. I don't want two User1 in returned query result.

Comment: You really don't want to use apex ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with that comment.

Comment: I mean my query will return the records in `order by createddate`.Then by simply iterating it and checking the condition you can grab what you want.

Comment: That would be plausible if I had a small data set. But it is not really performance and limit wise on larger data sets and might not return the result for every distinct lookup because of limitations. Maybe I should add this to question.

Comment: The only limitation i see is the query returns more then 50000 records.Otherwise we can optimize it as much as we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a bit of thought and help of a colleague I find the solution like this (but I did not test it extensively, **yet**. For now it seems to work just fine). Solution uses MAX function of soql. After finding MAX value for each created date grouping by user (or lookup field) I re-query with data in hand. This returns last inserted records.

```
        //getting lookup fields
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users = [SELECT Id FROM User];
        Set<Id> userIds = (new Map<Id,User>(users)).keySet();

        //getting max createdDate for users
        List<AggregateResult> records = [SELECT CreatedById, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM ObjectName WHERE CreatedById IN :userIds GROUP BY CreatedById];

        //put dates in a list
        Set<Datetime> cDates = new Set<Datetime>();
        For(AggregateResult record : records){
            cDates.add(Datetime.valueOf(record.get('expr0')));
        }

        //finally get last record for each user (or lookup field)
        List<ObjectName> latestRecords = [SELECT Id, SomeField__c FROM ObjectName WHERE CreatedById IN :userIds AND CreatedDate IN :cDates];
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you can limit this in a couple of different ways. One is by number of records returned, another is by using `TypeOf` (see [Working with Polymorphic Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) & you would need to have this feature enabled in your org) as well as `CreatedDate` of either `Yesterday`, `Today`, or `LAST_N_DAYS:n`. See [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) for more.

```
list<User>ListofUsers = new list<User>();

[Select FieldName from ObjectName where TypeOf Lookup = 'User' && Lookup in: ListofUsers 
    && (Createddate > YESTERDAY && Createddate < Now()) Limit n];
```

Note: You can use DateTime with Date functions in SOQL query WHERE clauses. See [Condition Expression Syntax (WHERE Clause)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm).

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev, thanks for your answer. But I really don't want to narrow down numbers of record returned because I have a lot of data come in every minutes from x number of users. If data from A user does not come for some number of days I might lost it in narrowing down process.

Comment: You're going to need to put some kind of limit on the number of records returned so it doesn't exceed 50k. You do that partly by narrowing the WHERE criteria and then limit the number of days or weeks you want to see data from. Otherwise, you're going to hit the query size limit. Plus, do you really want to receive 50k of records? What are you going to do with them if you get that many?

Comment: Btw, you can of course use OrderBy and GroupBy clauses on these as well.